# Controls for enterprise application- Angular2, ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

We are in an interesting stage- we are planning a web application for enterprise users. Our previous application, which we are re-writing, is written in Angular 1.5, bootstrapJs and AngularUi for bootstrapJs. 
**Are there good ui-control libraries that integrate with Angular2 or ReactJs (with Redux)**? For example tables with data binding, multi selects and more. We do not want to invest too much time on writing controls our selves if we go with one of these new technologies...

Answer (score 2):

As of today, here are the UI Componets you can use in your Angular 2 app:

- [ng-lightning](http://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/)
- [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/)
- [Wijmo](http://wijmo.com/products/wijmo-5/)
- [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/elements)
- [Angular Material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2)
- [Prime Faces](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/)

You can find the complete list of all UI Components that are currently available for Angular 2 in  **[Angular 2 Resources page](https://angular.io/resources/)**.

I personally used [*ng-lightning*](http://ng-lightning.github.io/ng-lightning/) and [*ng2-bootstrap*](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/) in my Angular 2 apps and they worked well for me.

Comment: thanks. any idea about a resource like this for react?